# NSWorkspace notification - application close

Tags: cocoa, nsworkspace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Close file using NSWorkspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232540/close-file-using-nsworkspace)

I use `NSWorkspace` to open a file. For example, I opened a  text file using TextEdit.
Now I'd like to get the event when the TextEdit closes the text file.

I notice that `NSWorkspace` has a notification center. But I tried all the notifications and none is what I want.

Could anyone help me how to catch this kind of event?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this answer, it may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7237698/1028709.

Comment: @JustinBoo，I think so, thanks! But How should deal with this post?